# Liquibase breaks backward compatibility with old PostgreSQL versions < 10 (serial vs identity columns)

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I have marked column like that:

```
<column name="id" type="bigserial">
    <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
</column>
```

which generates sequence and column with default value on version 9.x but identity on version 15:

```
id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL
```

1. How to keep it behaving like bigserial from sql in all versions?
2. Can I revert it back to bigserial without rewriting that changelog?
3. What are the pros of identity when I have to use sequence to do batch insert in spring boot?

Comment: The use of serial/bigserial is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) anyway

Comment: 9.X is EOL, even version 10 is EOL since last month